# getting href from anchor using ID is showing undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, href

I am trying to get the href attribute of an anchor using jQuery. However when I try to check the value of the variable where I placed the href attribute, it is saying undefined.

```
$("#chk1").click(function(){
    var button_link = $("#buttonAdd").find("href").attr('href');
    //or (I tried 2 ways)
    var button_link = $("#buttonAdd").attr('href');
    alert(button_link);
});
```

How do I properly capture the href attribute of an anchor using jQuery?

**EDIT:**

Adding the anchor link for your reference:

```
<a href="Vehicle/VehicleEditor.aspx?sfId=299798&amp;st=ON&amp;recloc=&amp;ID=&amp;manualReqID=0&amp;trID=21838518&amp;SeqNo=1" id="buttonAdd">Add</a>
```

Comment: You're going to get answers that are possibly wrong if you don't give us your HTML structure.

Comment: @RUJordan there you go.

Comment: lol we don't need the anchor, we need the parent structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find the `A` element. We can do this.

```
$("#buttonAdd").find("a").attr('href');
```

Comment: Or simply: `$("#buttonAdd a").attr('href');`

Comment: Whatever you want to do.

Comment: Good job deciphering that without any html structure shown. *If* this is correct that is.

Comment: @Adam Merrifield Thank you.

Comment: no need to find a, because Element A has ID #buttonAdd. $("#buttonAdd") is enough, and use $("a#buttonAdd") if you want more detail!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your HTML structure is, so I am assuming you have something like this:

1) parent div containing single  tag

> ```
>    <div id="buttonAdd">
>     <a href="href-here">...</a>
>     </div>
>     <button id="click-me">Click Me</button>
> ```

```
    $(function (){
     $("#click-me").click (function (){
         var H = $("#buttonAdd a").attr('href');
         alert (H);
        });
    });
```

2) <**A**> tag has an ID="buttonAdd"

```
    <a href="href-here" id="buttonAdd">Click Me</a>

    $(function (){
     $("#buttonAdd").click (function (){
         var H = $("this").attr('href');
         alert (H);
    });
 });
```